# Как указать папку загрузки файлов в расширении xupload в yii?

Tags: yii

Собственно, само расширение: [ссылка](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/xupload/).
Всё установил по мануалу - всё работает, но файлы сохраняются в папку:

```
/uploads/[какие-то-непонятные-цифры]/[имя-файла]
```

Видимо, так и задумано, но непонятно, что это за цифры в названии вложенной папки?

Как мне сделать так, чтоб загружаемые файлы сохранялись в папках с названиями в виде id?

Грубо говоря, надо загружать аватарки в папку: `/img/user/id-пользователя.jpg`,
а картинки объявлений в: `/img/ads/id-объявления/название-картинки.jpg`.

Также неясным остаётся момент с одновременной загрузкой файлов несколькими пользователями. Файлы грузятся все в одну папку или можно их разбить на папки, привязанные к пользователю?

Возможно, я не понимаю чего-то и есть простое решение этой проблемы.  
Извините, с yii работаю недавно...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здравствуйте!

Посмотрите класс actions/XUploadAction.php, там есть конфигурационная переменная $subfolderVar, описание которой гласит: **"Defaults to null meaning the subfolder to be used will be the result of date("mdY")"**, т.е. если Вы в настройках подключения не указали параметр subfolderVar, то расширение будет создавать папку названную по дате - ММДДГГГГ, это, я так понимаю, и есть Ваши "непонятные цифры".

Comment: Кстати, по-умолчанию в расширении название вложенной папки всегда date("mdY"). Видимо, недопилили или я снова туплю XD

Comment: А всё-таки какая папка является временной для загрузки файлов?

Comment: Временная папка указывается в настройках php (http://php.net/manual/ru/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir). Загруженные файлы перемещаются с помощью move_uploaded_file (подробнее здесь - http://php.net/manual/ru/function.move-uploaded-file.php).